# Oppeniddict - How to skip logout prompt?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, openiddict

I am using velusia sample, I want the client app to skip the log out prompt page, is there any specific way to achieve this, or should I implement it my self ?

Comment: Could you please tell me what you mean about skipping the log out prompt page. Do you mean you want directly log out without redirecting?

Comment: When the user clicks on logout he's redirected to Auth server and asked to confirm log out, I wan't to skip that and just log the user out and send him back to the client app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you handle logout requests is up to you. To trigger a redirection to the client application (when a `post_logout_redirect_uri` is set) without displaying a consent form, trigger an ASP.NET Core `Logout` operation pointing to OpenIddict:

```cs
// Returning a SignOutResult will ask OpenIddict to redirect the user agent
// to the post_logout_redirect_uri specified by the client application or to
// the RedirectUri specified in the authentication properties if none was set.
return SignOut(
    authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    properties: new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "/"
    });
```

That said, I wouldn't recommend doing that: not requiring user consent or a form of anti-forgery protection - the `id_token_hint` can help, use `AuthenticateAsync()` to retrieve the principal from it - may make targeted DOS attacks possible.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to set a js code to automatically click the logout button in the server side.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Modify the server's logout view as below:

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Log out</h1>
    <p class="lead text-left">Are you sure you want to sign out?</p>

    <form asp-controller="Authorization" asp-action="Logout" method="post">
        @* Flow the request parameters so they can be received by the LogoutPost action: *@
        @foreach (var parameter in Context.Request.HasFormContentType ?
           (IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>>) Context.Request.Form : Context.Request.Query)
        {
            <input type="hidden" name="@parameter.Key" value="@parameter.Value" />
        }

        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="Confirm" name="Confirm" type="submit" value="Yes" />
    </form>

  
</div>
@section scripts{

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Fired");
   document.getElementById("Confirm").click();
});
</script>
 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the HTTP method to GET instead of POST based on Velusia sample:

```cs
[HttpGet("logout")]
public async Task<IActionResult> LogoutPost()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(Clients.CmsApp);
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    return SignOut(
        authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        properties: new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "/"
        });
}
```